# exFAT USB router sharing

Tags: router, nas, exfat

I wish to plug in an USB drive to my router and be able to share the content across all connected devices.
The issue I have is that the drive is not seen and I think it's because the file system is exFAT.
Is there a way to make it work, if possible without formatting it?
From what I understand NTFS is windows only, and FAT32 does not support large files, so exFAT would be the only option for me.

Comment: 1) What does mean "the drive is not seen"? Not seen by the router, or seen by the router but not seen from the connected devices? 2) If not seen by the router you have to check the documentation of the router which file sytems it supports or not. 3) the file system of a network drive doesn't matter for the connected devices, which don't even see which filesystem it is, they just see a SMB network drive; the file system only matters for the router in your case.

Comment: According to the manual https://cdn-reichelt.de/documents/datenblatt/E910/ZYXEL_ARMOR_Z2_ANL-EN.pdf it should support FAT32 and NTFS. I also tried a NTFS drive and its still not seen anywhere. If I try to connect with SMB using the router internal ip, connection fails

Comment: You have to enable and configure the SMB sharing in the router settings (page 134): have you done so ?

Comment: yes, I tried with both guest and user/pw, still cannot login. Event tried FTP, and in the ftp client login I get to the login cmd and then it tells me that the password is incorrect (530). I think their firmware is buggy and I need to install openwrt :(

Comment: In case anyone else is wondering, I managed to "fix" this by flashing open wrt, then installing packages for usb, and exFat. It works only on usb2 port tho

Comment: You may write an answer to your own question